# Simplify expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Unclear what do here, can't find a similar example online. I need to simplify down this expression.

$$g(q(  (1-g)(1-f) ) ) - q(  (1-g)(1-f) )^2$$

I understand you don't need to provide the answer for me. Just a similar example so I can work this one out alone would be sufficient

All g and f are numbers.  q is also numbers e.g q=0.5

Comment: I take it, $f$ and $g$ are numbers? What about $P$ and $q$? They're written as functions. If so, you have to say *what* functions. Otherwise noting can be done.

Comment: I think it's pretty simple as it stands, I don't see how you could improve this expression. There are maybe a few brackets too many, but that's all I can think of.

Comment: @raskolnikov sorry there was an error in expression.   Sorry thank for your comment

Answer (score 3):

You have a difference between two terms:  $A-B$.

The second term $B$  is $q((1-g)(1-f))^2 = q(1-g)(1-f)(1-g)(1-f)$, so it is a product of 5 factors, among them $(1-f)$.  So $B = (...)*(1-f)$.

Write the first term $A$ also as a product of factors, among them again $(1-f)$. 
$A = (.....)*(1-f)$.

Now apply distributivity:   $(.....)*(1-f) - (...)*(1-f) = (.... - ...)*(1-f)$.

(Note that distributivity $ax-bx=(a-b)x$ works even if $x$ is a more complicated expression, such as $(1-f)$.)

Once you have done that, you will see how to simplify further.